# Creating a Point with SRID - MariaDB

Tags: point, sql, geometry, mariadb

I have a table containing a `longitude` and `latitude` (as doubles) in MariaDB. What I'm trying to do is create a point with a specific SRID - 4326. The current way that I create a point is by using the following code:

```
POINT(table1.`longitude`, table1.`latitude`)
```

But this way doesn't allow for me to set an SRID. I did look at other questions regarding this, but they seem to be limited to wkt formats.

---

What I did try was research MariaDB's functions and tried the following code:

```
ST_PointFromWKB(POINT(table1.`longitude`, table1.`latitude`), [,4326])
```

The error I seem to be receiving is: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '[,4326])`

MariaDB's functions seem to be very briefly explained, can anyone provide any tips?

Comment: I think you just need to remove the square brackets  around 4326.  Instead you would have `ST_PointFromWKB(POINT(tabke1.longitude, table1.latitude), 4326);

Answer (score 0):

Edit: The problem is probably your square-brackets. Those indicate that the parameter is optional in the documentation, but should not be present in the code.

```
    ST_PointFromWKB(POINT(table1.`longitude`, table1.`latitude`), 4326)
```

Earlier answer: You need to convert it to binary format for the `ST_PointFromWKB`-function.

```
    ST_PointFromWKB(ST_AsBinary(POINT(1,1)), 4326);
```

I use this, more general function, which take any type of `GEOMETRY`, not only Point.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION `fn_attach_srid`(
            in_geometry GEOMETRY
            , in_srid INT
        ) RETURNS GEOMETRY
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
    COMMENT ''
    BEGIN
        RETURN ST_GeomFromWKB(ST_AsBinary(in_geometry), in_srid);
    END
    GO
```

Usage:

```
    SELECT fn_attach_srid(POINT(1,1), 4326);
```

Comment: POINT returns a binary representation, no need to convert it to binary.  See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/point/

Comment: Seems to be right, can't remember why I needed it. I'm updating.